# Insert String Into Django URL in JQuery Load

Tags: python, jquery, django

I'm new to JQuery, Django and web development in general. I'm trying to figure out how to insert a string into the URL in the JQuery load function based on HTML data, but I'm getting reverse URL errors. I have view that returns a rendered HTML table from a file given a search query:

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [ ...
     path('database/<search>', views.db_search, name='db_search'),
 ... ]
```

**views.py**

```
def db_search(request, search):
     return render(request, 'app/Content/database.htm', {'context': context})
```

This works fine when I hard-code the search string in JQuery as:

```
$(".filterBtn").click(function(){
            $("#mainpanel").load("{% url 'db_search' 'str_param' %}");
     });
```

The problem is that there are multiple filter buttons which are dynamically generated by Django based on the state of the database. I don't want to hard-code the search parameters (nor should I). What I want to do is something like:

```
$(".filterBtn").click(function(){
            $("#mainpanel").load("{% url 'db_search' this.innerText %}");
     });
```

but Django throws reverse URL errors because "this.innerText" isn't defined.

> Reverse for 'db_search' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s)
>   tried: ['database/(?P[^/]+)$']

Am I missing something? It seems like this should be pretty straightforward.

Comment: You may get a better response if you give a minimum reproducible example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) rather than individual snippets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works fine

```
"{% url '<app-name>:<url-name>' <parameter>  %}"
```

**EXAMPLE**

URL:

```
    path("<str:username>/", view=user_detail_view , name="detail"),
```

TEMPLATE:

```
<a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'users:detail' request.user.username  %}">{% trans "My Profile" %}</a>
```

where users is my app-name

detail is the url name

request.user.username is the parameter to view

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I changed my approach to just reload the whole page from a template rather than pass new HTML to a container in the page. Using hyperlinks rather than buttons let me ditch jQuery: 
{% for tag in materialclass.tags %}
     <a href="{% url 'db_search' tag.tagshort %}">{{ tag.label }}</a>
{% endfor %}
The only problem is that now I lose the state of my nav menu when the page reloads, but that's probably a different issue.